# Jetty 9: run own code at startup

Tags: java, jetty

I am using jetty server version 9 (not embedded),

and I want to run several threads when the server starts which will be running always until server is shut down.

How should I do it in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not running embedded then you probably want to avoid a jetty specific solution using our LifeCycle objects and instead do something that is a little more general servlet-api related.  Take a look into the ServletContextListener for a chance to tap into the startup and stopping of a servlet context.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html